# Bathroom flooring: tile with grout additive VS vinyl

Tags: bathroom, tile, vinyl-flooring, vinyl

For a bathroom, which is easier to clean and maintain in the long run? Tile? Vinyl?
Also, adding grout additives to prevent mold in the future is worth the extra money?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can give you one huge pro, and that is with ceramic tile or stone, properly installed, you can have a completely waterproof bathroom. Where vinyl plank, although reasonably water resistant, does not like standing water for any length of time. I've been seeing vinyl flooring being pulled up in bathrooms these days due to water damage of the sub floor. The key with vinyl plank in a bathroom is to apply a bead of clear silicone around the entire perimeter of the bathroom. Now some will say this wont work because of expansion and contraction, but I say:

1. I do it all the time, and
2. It doesn't expand and contract that much, and
3. Silicone caulk is extremely flexible.

The pros of vinyl would be excellent durability, resilience to cracking and it feels warmer on your feet because PVC is an insulator. Stone and tile, however stores heat, making it the best option for a heated floor.

Comment: Bathrooms probably need water proof instead of water resistant.

Comment: a smidge of formatting makes it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Tile, if installed correctly, is easier to clean and almost indestructible. Rather than add additives to the grout, think about using epoxy grout. It's waterproof and doesn't need to be sealed. It also doesn't crack. It's a little harder to work with but well worth the effort. Any mold that does form will only be surface mold which won't happen with normal cleaning.

Comment: There are also many acrylic based grouts now that dont need sealing, don't leach color and are antimicrobial as well and a bit easier to work with than epoxy, but not as easy as cement based.